# Deactivate postgres user account

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to deactivate a postgres user account via an SQL statement?

I want to prevent a user from using their database, but without deleting the user or their databases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [REVOKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-revoke.html) command.

In order for a user to connect to a database he has been granted the CONNECT privilege.
Just REVOKE this privilege and he won't be able to use this database.

Answer (score 22):

You might also consider `ALTER USER someone WITH NOLOGIN;` which is probably the right solution if you have multiple databases in the same back-end and want to block the user entirely.

**To lock an account:**

```
# Lock an account
ALTER USER someone WITH NOLOGIN;
```

**To unlock an account:**

```
# Un-lock an account
ALTER USER someone WITH LOGIN;
```

**Check account is locked or not:**

```
select rolcanlogin from pg_roles where rolname='database_user';

OUTPUT:
rolcanlogin
-------------
 f
(1 row)

f = false # Can not login
t = true # Can login
```